# Detecting network activity in C

Tags: c, sockets, networking, signals

If I lose connection to a server, I start an alarm to go off in 10 minutes. In the meantime I try to create a socket and re-establish a connection to the server. If when the alarm goes off, there is no connection to the server, I want to close the application.

What would be a good way to go about checking if there is a live connection on a socket? I am unsure if blocking methods are acceptable (obviously if there is no alternative they are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I lose connection to a server, I start an alarm to go off in 10 minutes.

So at that point you knew there was no connection.

> In the meantime I try to create a socket and re-establish a connection to the server. If when the alarm goes off, there is no connection to the server, I want to close the application.
>
> What would be a good way to go about checking if there is a live connection on a socket? I am unsure if blocking methods are acceptable (obviously if there is no alternative they are).

If you knew there was no connection when you set the alarm, why don't you know the same thing when it expires?

It seems to me that all you need to do is examine the socket fd. If it is non-zero you have a connection; if it is zero you don't. And make sure you zero it when you set the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Just save a result of "connect()" function anywhere, so you will be able to check it in 10 minutes.

Comment: Not downvoting this, but if I was the person asking this question, I'm not sure this answer would help me. A little more detail wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be a good way to go about checking if there is a live connection on a socket? I am unsure if blocking methods are acceptable (obviously if there is no alternative they are).

I Assume from this question end the explanation above that you have the idea how to handle a lost connection but don't know how to check if the connection is still alive.

Best way to check if the connection is still alive is to send periodically a dummy / heartbeat / keep-alive message to the server. As soon as the connection is dead the tcp socket will give you an error (after the timeout) so you know that the connection died and you can try to reconnect / flag the alarm etc.